# Update one dataframe from another with qualifiers

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to replicate SQL `UPDATE`-type functionality in `pandas`. I've seen other solutions suggesting using `pandas` `update` method or `merge` and dropping columns.

Example dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,False, None], [1,True, None], [1, False, 'UpdateMe'], [2,True, None]], columns=['id', 'value1', 'value2'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,True, 'Updated'], [2,True, 'Updated']], columns=['id', 'value1', 'value2'])
```

Here is the SQL I am trying to replicate:

```
UPDATE df1
SET value1 = df2.value1, value2 = df2.value2
FROM df1
JOIN df2 ON df1.id = df2.id
WHERE df1.value2 = 'UpdateMe';
```

I can get the update to work without any qualifier like so:

```
df1.set_index('id', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('id', inplace=True)

df1.update(df2, overwrite=True)
df1.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
df1

    id  value1  value2
0   1   TRUE    Updated
1   1   TRUE    Updated
2   1   TRUE    Updated
3   2   TRUE    Updated
```

However, when I add a qualifier to which records in the dataframe to update, I get a warning and the target dataframe does not get updated.

```
df1.set_index('id', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('id', inplace=True)

df1.loc[
    df1.value2 == 'UpdateMe'
].update(df2, overwrite=True)

SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self[col] = expressions.where(mask, this, that)
```

Here is the expected output:

```
    id  value1  value2
0   1   FALSE   
1   1   TRUE    
2   1   TRUE    Updated
3   2   TRUE
```

Any suggestion on how to update multiple columns with a `.loc` or type of where clause?

Comment: None of the code above contains 'UpdateMe" under df1.value2. Can you please check again?

Comment: @ian just did - sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can create temporary columns using merge. Then, user np.where similar to =If() function in excel. Next, remove the temporary columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,False, None], [1,True, None], [1, False, 'UpdateMe'], [2,True, None]], columns=['id', 'value1', 'value2'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,True, 'Updated'], [2,True, 'Updated']], columns=['id', 'value1', 'value2'])
df1.set_index('id', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('id', inplace=True)

#Answer
df1 = df1.merge(df2.rename(columns = {'value1':'value1_temp','value2':'value2_temp'}), how = 'left', right_index = True, left_index = True)

df1.value1 = np.where(df1.value2 == 'UpdateMe', df1.value1_temp, df1.value1)
df1.value2 = np.where(df1.value2 == 'UpdateMe', df1.value2_temp, df1.value2)

df1 = df1.drop(labels = ['value1_temp','value2_temp'], axis = 1)

df1
```